# Assign values to a name within a function

Tags: r, assign

Here is my code:

```
get_test <- function(name){
  data <- filter(data_all_country,country == name)
  # transform the data to a time series using `ts` in `stats`
  data <- ts(data$investment, start = 1950)
  data <- log(data)
  rule <- substitute(name)
  assign(rule,data)
}
```

As in the code, I try to build a function by which I could input a country's name given in character string, and then the variable named by the country would be generated automatically. However, I run this code, and it runs but with no exact variable generated as I want. For example, I want to have a variable called `Albania` in the environment after I code `get_test("Albania")`.

I wonder why?

Ps: And the dataset of `data_all_country` is as following:

```
    year country investment
1 1950 Albania         NA
2 1951 Albania         NA
3 1952 Albania         NA
4 1953 Albania         NA
5 1954 Albania         NA
6 1955 Albania         NA
```

Note that the dataset is OK, just some of it is `NA`

Comment: Your description makes no mention of ts(). Reduce your example to the essentials.  Also show the code that calls the fn.

Comment: Hi, @42 , `ts` is a function to transform into the time series.

Comment: may be it is `ts(data$data_all_country.investment, start = 1950)`

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, the dataset is an example using the function `data.frame()` to avoid so many unnecessary columns, the $ part is of no problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to specify the environment for `assign`, else it will use the current environment (in this case within the function).

You could use

```
assign(name, data, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

or

```
assign(name, data, pos = 1)
```